# how to kill processes on mac os x over ssh to linux

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, terminal

Well, have ssh'd from my mac to my linux computer, and now I wonder how on earth do I send a kill signal like you do in windows = ctrl-c?

I tried every combination with macs keyboard layout + C
and it wont work..

Answer (score 0):

whats about *exit* or *logout*? worked for me to exit any shell to a remote computer.

Comment: i dont want to exit or logout, i want to shut down a running process that have freezed or whatever in my shell.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux (and most other Unix variants, including Mac) the key combination to exit the shell is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. That signals the end of the input (EOF), causing the shell (and ssh connection) to exit.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a particular signal to the active program. It will cause most programs to exit, but some (like the shell) do something slightly different when they get it, e.g. the shell will cancel the current command line and move to the next.